# pandas - number of unique rows occurrences in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I count number of occurrences of each unique row in a `DataFrame`?

```
data = {'x1': ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','A'], 'x2': [1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  x1  x2
0  A   1
1  B   3
2  A   2
3  A   2
4  B   3
5  A   1
6  A   2
7  A   3
```

And I would like to obtain

```
   x1  x2 count 
0   A   1     2
1   A   2     3
2   A   3     1
3   B   3     2
```

Comment: Sorry what's wrong with your current approach? Or are you expecting `4` at the end based on `len(df.groupby(['x1','x2']).count())`?

Comment: I cannot obtain the `count` column. My code returns `Empty DataFrame`.

Comment: Are you after `df['count'] = df.groupby(['x1','x2'])['x1'].transform('count')`?

Comment: is this what you're after `df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).count()`?

Comment: @EdChum Yes, the last one is the one, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIUC you can pass param `as_index=False` as an arg to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby):

```
In [100]:
df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).count()

Out[100]:
  x1  x2  count
0  A   1      2
1  A   2      3
2  A   3      1
3  B   3      2
```

Comment: I'm not sure if pandas has changed something that broke this answer, but when I try this it does NOT add a ```count``` column:  ```df = {'x1': ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','A'], 'x2': [1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3]}; 
df = pd.DataFrame(df); 
df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).count(); ```

Comment: The `count` has been changed to `value_counts`

Answer (score 13):

You could also drop duplicated rows:

```
In [4]: df.shape[0]
Out[4]: 8

In [5]: df.drop_duplicates().shape[0]
Out[5]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can find unique occurence in your dataframe.

1st: Using drop_duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates().sort_values('x1',ignore_index=True)
```

2nd: Using groupby.nunique

```
df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).nunique()
```

For finding the number of occurrences, the answer from @EdChum will work precisely.