# Count number of unique row in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to count the number of unique rows in a pandas dataframe. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551335/pandas-number-of-unique-rows-occurrences-in-dataframe) but it generates an error.

This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = {'x1': ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','A'], 'x2': [1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).count()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace/project/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 4372, in count
    return self._wrap_agged_blocks(data.items, list(blk))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 4274, in _wrap_agged_blocks
    index = np.arange(blocks[0].values.shape[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it by using `size`(ps: you can add `.reset_index()` at the end)

```
df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).size()
Out[1262]: 
x1  x2
A   1     2
    2     3
    3     1
B   3     2
dtype: int64
```

Or fix your code

```
df.groupby(['x1','x2'])['x2'].count()
Out[1264]: 
x1  x2
A   1     2
    2     3
    3     1
B   3     2
Name: x2, dtype: int64
```

If you want to know the unique groups, you can using `ngroups`

```
df.groupby(['x1','x2']).ngroups
Out[1267]: 4
```

Comment: thx, this is perfect: print df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).size().reset_index()

Comment: @DanixDanilovic In that case you could use: `df.groupby(list(df.columns),as_index=False).size().reset_index()` which is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'x1': ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','A'], 'x2': [1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(len(df.drop_duplicates()))
```

Returns

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of occurences of unique rows in the dataframe, instead of using `count`, you should use `value_counts` now.

```
df.groupby(['x1','x2'], as_index=False).value_counts()
Out[417]: 
  x1  x2  count
0  A   1      2
1  A   2      3
2  A   3      1
3  B   3      2
```